# Birds Eye View Bing Maps Not working on WPF App C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winrt-xaml, bing-maps

Im actually working on a MVVM WPF App. There was bing maps integrated within the application, and everything is working correctly on the maps except the Birds Eye View Mode. The API key was probably created in 2012 and the project was also created in 2012. The birds eye view map is ok above 10km but below, i just have a white screen.

Anyone knows if this may be linked due the fact that it may be outdated? 
Road and Satellite are actually working correctly to any distance, only birds eye view is not working .

WPF App/C#/Win 8.1 Project

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Which map control are you using? If this project is from 2012, it was probably the V7.0 HTML control. This control has been deprecated and projects should be moved to the new V8.0 control. To assist developers, when the V7 control is requested, a wrapper around the V8 control is returned instead that works for most scenarios. Bird's Eye works differently in V8, so might not be possible for the default migration wrapper to work. You should look at this guide: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34563.bing-maps-v7-to-v8-migration-guide.aspx